# Regaining trust in the graduate school system? R2 Ph.D student with a history of getting burned by my Master's and PhD programs

Tags: publications, research-process, graduate-school, teaching, internship

I know I've posted a fair amount on this site but to briefly introduce myself, I'm a 4th year doctoral candidate in Experimental Psychology with an accepted Master's from a regional college in Experimental Psychology as well. I'm making this post to "come clean" about why I spend so much time worrying about things. As far as justifying why this post would be useful to others goes (something I know I have to consider when making these posts now), I imagine it would be useful for my peers who are also at R2s downsizing graduate programs and/or are/were in departments filled to the brim with drama inside the department and their administration like mine.

Coming into this question, I'm approaching it from the perspective of someone who has been burned quite often or was misinformed about graduate school roles. I'm also a first generation college student so these "unwritten rules" were/are foreign to me until someone spells them out to me (I'm also autistic so I miss cues often). Notable examples:

1.) My Master's program only graduated 9/13 folks (well below the 85% graduation rate for most universities) and didn't try to convince them to stick around to finish. One left after a year and the other was 2.5 years into the program and quit due to advisor drama and insisting the advisee collect data on elderly individuals after COVID hit. She didn't do herself any favors imo with missing class often to work (since my Master's was partially funded not fully funded). It was wild news overall though since she was a valedictorian in her undergrad!

2.) I had extremely suboptimal performance in my Master's program (3.48 GPA, B and B+ in Spring sessions of 1 credit hour seminar courses because I got Cs both times on presentations). My LORs were also fine but they weren't great either since I was the only one in my cohort who didn't take another 10 hours of an assistantship for the opportunity to get supervised by someone who could write me one. I didn't do other research projects either. The whole reason was because I thought advisors told someone when to get involved and not get involved with other things beyond the bare minimum. Based on what my peers were doing, I can say I was wrong there.

3.) Despite this, I got into an Experimental Psychology program at an R2 that happened to be a sister school of my undergrad and Master's programs respectively. I got all As and A-s in a year's worth of elective coursework I had to take before I was officially cut loose into not having to take classes. Unfortunately, my first advisor dumped me over a misunderstanding. Even though she was slated to leave the university anyway, she planned on advising me from afar prior to this incident. It also involved "how I was born" (i.e., being autistic) as she put it and that leading to disorganization she saw. Even though I went to three different offices and places, I had no choice but to keep working with my advisor until my August 15th deadline to have my qualifier project totally signed off.

4.) A Ph.D advisor infamously dumped a different advisee in my program last academic year and, unlike me, no one stepped up to take her as an advisee. My current advisor is someone who has taken "orphaned advisees" in the past so I got lucky.

5.) Tuition waiver was kept my 3rd year of my PhD program before my funding was set to run out (since my program was paid off at that point), albeit my stipend was cut in half compared to my first two years! My program also suspended admissions to their Clinical Psychology program for this reason (no funding for first year students).

Despite my recent luck and all of my experiences, I've been told on here and other places that my programs all have a vested interest in their students graduating and that I should continue to trust the process (and produce in turn) for that reason. Based on my experiences and seeing what happened to others though... I'm just not seeing that at all. I'm doing what I can to graduate but it's ultimately going to be the bare minimum (e.g., no publications) simply because I've seen how often others got diminishing returns on their Master's and PhDs respectively. It took me a long time to become self aware that all of this was the reason underpinning my behavior but here we are now. "Concentrating on what I need to do to make it happen" (as one comment put it) is helpful but it reinforces that I need to protect myself constantly.

As much as I'd like to press forward and do the additional stuff that are soft expectations (e.g., publications) with the extra time afforded by being done with classes, I really think I'm better off just continuing to focus on applying for internships, post graduation jobs, my full time visiting SLAC position, and trying to restore myself to an optimal level of functioning. That said, I've had the process of getting published drilled in my head constantly and going beyond the bare minimum. How can I regain trust in the process at this point given what's happened to me?

As usual, if this breaks any rules or needs modification, I won't take any offense if I know or am told about it.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? We can be pretty sure that your school is not out to get you. Not because schools are inherently good, but because you are not important enough for the school to care. Can you trust such uncaring institutions? Yes, in the very limited sense that they are predictable.

Comment: None of that helps you. Your first step is for you to figure out what you want. You sound like you feel trapped in this career path.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I feel trapped to an extent but that's only because I don't know what I can reasonably do given my current differences. That's why I'm hoping these job matching programs can find something for me because it's not about what I want anymore. It's all about what I can do.

Comment: This is way too specific to be a good fit here. You should look at how I edited [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/205229/revisions) question and do the same thing to your own questions.

Comment: @cag51 Dang it. Wish I saw this before I made my post just now. Might just edit it on my own if I have the chance to before I got to bed now.